# Can't Publish SubProjects with Gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle project, it has jvm (Scala) subprojects, and I want to publish all of their jars to a m2 repository.

I applied `maven-publish` like this ...

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

    publishing {
        repositories {
            // path to somewhere in my repo
            maven { url new File(project.rootProject.getProjectDir().absoluteFile.parentFile, ".m2-repo") }
        }
    }
}
```

... but it only publishes the root project. I've tried running `publish` from the subprojects; I get an up-to-date message but nothing is added to the repo on disk.

I'm using the 4.0.1 GradeWrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be;

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    repositories {
        // publish to a "local" repo that I can also consume or upload as I wish
        maven { url new File(project.rootProject.getProjectDir().absoluteFile.parentFile, ".m2-repo") }
    }

    // really, really publish things
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can actually put both repositories and publications under the same closure `publishing `.